# Strange line appears in shape after changing camera angle

Tags: java, javafx

[image][image]I have a program that constitutes a Cube class that extends from the Group class, in this Cube I create a Polygon that serves as one of the faces of this Cube, when facing it it renders normal, but when the camera perspective rotates back the polygon of After creating a strange white line over the front one, I noticed that this happens due to the order in which items are created and added to the container via getChildren (). add (), this line cannot be rendered independent the order in which cubes and faces are created and added to the container?

Class cube.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Point3D;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.CacheHint;
import javafx.scene.DepthTest;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.CornerRadii;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
import javafx.scene.transform.Translate;

public class Cube extends Group{

    public final Rotate rx = new Rotate(0, Rotate.X_AXIS);
    public final Rotate ry = new Rotate(0, Rotate.Y_AXIS);
    public final Rotate rz = new Rotate(0, Rotate.Z_AXIS);
    public final Translate translate;
    public final double x;
    public final double y;
    public final double z;
    public final Group group;
    public static final ArrayList<Cube> instances = new ArrayList<Cube>();

    public static final int A_LEFT = 0;
    public static final int A_RIGHT = 1;
    public static final int A_TOP = 2;
    public static final int A_BOTTOM = 3;
    public static final int A_FRONT = 4;
    public static final int A_BACK = 5;

    public Cube(double tam, double x, double y, double z, Color cor, Group grupo) {
        this.group = grupo;
        setDepthTest(DepthTest.ENABLE);
        setCacheHint(CacheHint.SCALE_AND_ROTATE);
        setCache(true);
        Cube.instances.add(this);
        //System.out.print(Cube.instances.size());
        grupo.getChildren().add(this);
        this.x = x; 
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;

        translate = new Translate(x,y,z);

        getTransforms().addAll(rx,ry,rz, translate);

        Button b = new Button("Test Button");
        b.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<Event>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(Event event) {
                System.out.println("Test click");
            }

        });

        HBox frontFace = this.createFace(tam, tam, tam*-0.5, tam*-0.5, tam*-0.5, Rotate.X_AXIS, 0, cor.deriveColor(0.0, 1.0, (1 - 0.5 * 1), 1.0));
        HBox backFace = this.createFace(tam, tam, tam*-0.5, tam*-0.5, tam*0.5, Rotate.Y_AXIS, 180d, cor.deriveColor(0.0, 1.0, (1 - 0.4 * 1), 1.0));
        HBox leftFace = this.createFace(tam, tam, tam*-1, tam*-0.5, 0, Rotate.Y_AXIS, 90d, cor.deriveColor(0.0, 1.0, (1 - 0.3 * 1), 1.0));
        HBox rightFace = this.createFace(tam, tam, 0, tam*-0.5, 0, Rotate.Y_AXIS, -90d, cor.deriveColor(0.0, 1.0, (1 - 0.2 * 1), 1.0));
        HBox bottomFace = this.createFace(tam, tam, tam*-0.5, 0, 0, Rotate.X_AXIS, 90d, cor.deriveColor(0.0, 1.0, (1 - 0.1 * 1), 1.0));
        HBox topFace = this.createFace(tam, tam, tam*-0.5, tam*-1, 0, Rotate.X_AXIS, -90d, cor.deriveColor(0.0, 1.0, (1 - 0.6 * 1), 1.0));

        Polygon polygon = new Polygon();
        polygon.getPoints().addAll(new Double[]{
            55.0, 0.0,
            110.0, 110.0,
            0.0, 110.0
            });

        polygon.setStroke(Color.BROWN);
        polygon.setStrokeWidth(0);
        polygon.setSmooth(false);
        polygon.setCacheHint(CacheHint.SCALE_AND_ROTATE);

        backFace.getChildren().add(polygon);
        backFace.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.TRANSPARENT, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
        polygon.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        polygon.setStroke(null);

      //  leftFace.getChildren().add(polygon2);

        ImageView anImage = new ImageView(new Image("android.png",110,110,false,true));

        anImage.setFitWidth(100);
        anImage.setPreserveRatio(true);
        anImage.setCacheHint(CacheHint.SCALE_AND_ROTATE);
        anImage.setSmooth(true);
        anImage.setCache(true); 

       // backFace.getChildren().add(anImage);

        /*BackgroundImage myBI= new BackgroundImage(new Image("android.png",110,110,false,true),
                BackgroundRepeat.REPEAT, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.DEFAULT,
                  BackgroundSize.DEFAULT);*/

        //frontFace.setBackground(new Background(myBI));

        frontFace.setStyle("-fx-background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0)");

        rightFace.setOnMouseClicked(e -> this.createNextCube(e, Cube.A_RIGHT));
        leftFace.setOnMouseClicked(e -> this.createNextCube(e, Cube.A_LEFT));
        topFace.setOnMouseClicked(e -> this.createNextCube(e, Cube.A_TOP));
        bottomFace.setOnMouseClicked(e -> this.createNextCube(e, Cube.A_BOTTOM));
        frontFace.setOnMouseClicked(e -> this.createNextCube(e, Cube.A_FRONT));
        backFace.setOnMouseClicked(e -> this.createNextCube(e, Cube.A_BACK));

        //frontFace.getChildren().addAll(b);

        getChildren().addAll(
            frontFace,
            leftFace,
            rightFace,
            topFace,
            bottomFace,
            backFace
        );
    }

    public HBox createFace(double w, double h, double x, double y, double z, Point3D axis, double rotation, Color cor) {
        HBox g = new HBox();
        g.setPrefSize(w, h);
        g.setTranslateX(x);
        g.setTranslateY(y);
        g.setTranslateZ(z);

        g.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        g.setRotationAxis(axis);
        g.setRotate(rotation);
        g.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(cor, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));

        return g;
    }

    public Cube createNextCube(MouseEvent e, int side) {
        if(e.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
            double px = this.x;
            double py = this.y;
            double pz = this.z;

            switch(side) {
            case Cube.A_RIGHT:
                px += 110;
            break;
            case Cube.A_LEFT:
                px -= 110;
            break;
            case Cube.A_TOP:
                py -= 110;
            break;
            case Cube.A_BOTTOM:
                py += 110;
            break;
            case Cube.A_FRONT:
                pz -= 110;
            break;
            case Cube.A_BACK:
                pz += 110;
            break;
            }

            return new Cube(110, px, py, pz, Color.ALICEBLUE, this.group);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Class main.java

```
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.CacheHint;
import javafx.scene.DepthTest;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.PerspectiveCamera;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.SceneAntialiasing;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
import javafx.scene.transform.Translate;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Main extends Application{

    private PerspectiveCamera camera;
    private Rotate cameraRotateX, cameraRotateY, cameraRotateZ;
    private double antX;
    private double antY;


    public void init(Stage primaryStage) {
            camera = new PerspectiveCamera();
            cameraRotateX = new Rotate(0, Rotate.X_AXIS);
            cameraRotateY = new Rotate(0, Rotate.Y_AXIS);
            cameraRotateZ = new Rotate(0, Rotate.Z_AXIS);

            Translate cameraTranslate = new Translate(-700 / 2, -300 / 2, 0);
            camera.getTransforms().addAll(
                    cameraRotateX,
                    cameraRotateY,
                    cameraRotateZ,
                    cameraTranslate);
            Group root = new Group();
            root.setDepthTest(DepthTest.ENABLE);
            primaryStage.setResizable(true);
            primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 700, 300, true, SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED));
            primaryStage.getScene().setCamera(camera);
           // root.getTransforms().addAll(
                    //new Translate(700 / 2, 300 / 2),
                    //new Rotate(180, Rotate.X_AXIS)
           // );

            //Group gp = new Group();
           // gp.setDepthTest(DepthTest.);
            //gp.setCache(true);
            camera.setNearClip(0.01);

            Cube cubo = new Cube(110, 0,0,0, Color.RED, root);

            Timeline animation = new Timeline();
            animation.getKeyFrames().addAll(
                    new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO,
                            new KeyValue(cubo.ry.angleProperty(), 0d),
                            new KeyValue(cubo.rx.angleProperty(), 0d)
                    ),
                    new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(30),
                            new KeyValue(cubo.ry.angleProperty(), 360d),
                            new KeyValue(cubo.rx.angleProperty(), 360d)
                    )
            );

            animation.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);

            //root.getChildren().add(gp);

            root.setCache(true);
           // root.setCacheHint(CacheHint.SCALE_AND_ROTATE);

            //animation.play();

            primaryStage.getScene().setOnMousePressed(e -> pressed(e));
            primaryStage.getScene().setOnMouseDragged(e -> moved(e));
            primaryStage.getScene().setOnScroll(e -> cameraTranslate.setZ(cameraTranslate.getZ()+e.getDeltaY()));
            primaryStage.getScene().heightProperty().addListener(h -> cameraTranslate.setY(-1*(primaryStage.getScene().getHeight())/2));
            primaryStage.getScene().widthProperty().addListener(w -> cameraTranslate.setX(-1*(primaryStage.getScene().getWidth())/2));
    }

    public void pressed(MouseEvent ev) {
        antX = ev.getSceneX();
        antY = ev.getSceneY();
    }

    public void moved(MouseEvent ev) {

        double movX = ev.getSceneX() - antX;
        double movY = ev.getSceneY() - antY;

        cameraRotateX.setAngle(cameraRotateX.getAngle() + movY);
        cameraRotateY.setAngle(cameraRotateY.getAngle() + movX);

        antX = ev.getSceneX();
        antY = ev.getSceneY();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage palco) throws Exception {
        init(palco);
        palco.show();
    }

}
```